# Embed technique

Tags: javascript, styles, embed

I'm looking for a good way for webmasters to embed content from my website providing them with a simple javascript snippet.

Two things:

- if I attached a stylesheet, won't it break theirs?
- inline or attached CSS, their is still a risk that their style breaks mine?

what is the technique used by FB or Youtube to allow embed content, without using iframes?

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

FB uses iframes.

You can make a content.html file you or other pages can load via ajax. Where content.html does not contain the whole page but just a content part. Like:

```
<h1>This is important</h1>
<p>here is some text.</p>
```

For example with jQuery you can place place a html file in a div like this: `$('#result').load('content.html');`

But I think it depends on what you want to share and to who. Maybe a REST API would work better in you case?

Comment: If I use this kind of technique, it won't break the styles of the page that embed the content? and the embedded content won't have the style of the "host" applied to it?

Comment: You don't need to place styles in the file. You just have plain HTML. Everyone can apply it's own CSS style to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an impression, but actually Facebook and other social networks do use Iframes. But they're created by their JS that you also have to embed, making the their tech choices more powerful. Later on they might update the JS and then get rid of the iframe in favour of something else.

However, currently, you embed a div with a given CSS class an a `data-href`, plus the JS. The script will find those divs `.fb-post` and fill it in with an iframe containing the post indicated by the data attribute.

If you want to make something simpler you might as well give your users an iframe with a responsive page inside it.